# How to group and select multiple object in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
PersonList = PersonList
           .GroupBy(s => s.LastName)
           .Select(g => new Person { 
                LastName = g.Key,
                Period = g.Select(p => p.Period), 
                Time = string.Join("  ", g.Select(v => CheckTime(v.Time, v.Period) + "' " + v.Gtype)) })
           .ToList();
```

I have this linq statement and I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collection.Generic.Ienumerable<string>` to `'string'`.

Is it possible to select multiple properties of the object of person

Comment: You are already selecting properties from _Person_ object right? The error is because your query is returning `List<Person>` and you are trying to store it in a variable of type _string_.

Comment: What datatype is `Period` in Person?

Comment: Can you *describe* what you are trying to achieve with this query - you are getting some aggregated data for people by their LastName, but what is stored in Period of person?

Comment: Can you give us the definition of `Person` and `CheckTime`?

Comment: I think you have Period defined as a 'string'.  g.Select(p => p.Period) will return a List<> object.  So try this : g.Select(p => p.Period).FirfstOrDefault();

Comment: @jdweng why `FirstOrDefault()`? Why not Join or Last?

Comment: Period is a string.  I would like the last name to be the key only and the new Person Object should also have the property of Period and Time.

Key: LastName
Properties:
Period
Time
and possible other in the future.

Comment: Often when you have a List like Person all the items in the list will have the same value.  For example if you have a class 5 days a week the class will always start at the same time like 9:00AM.  So it doesn't matter if you take the first item or the last you will get the same time.  Without using FirstOrDefault() you will have an array and won't be able to set the array to a string.  Using string Join also can be used to convert the array to a string.

Comment: @Ikram Turgunbaev answer worked for me. But curious to know what all the other solution does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify like this

Your code:

```
Period = g.Select(p => p.Period)
```

Modified code:

```
Period = g.Select(p => p.Period).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want unique groups for lastname and period (and not something like the first period in the name group), you can group on both LastName and Period with `.GroupBy(s => new{s.LastName, s.Period})`. The key will contain both properties:

```
PersonList = PersonList
       .GroupBy(s => new {s.LastName, s.Period})
       .Select(g => new Person { 
            LastName = g.Key.LastName,
            Period = g.Key.Period,
            Time = string.Join("  ", g.Select(v => CheckTime(v.Time, v.Period) + "' " + v.Gtype)) })
       .ToList();
```